# What is a lot of traffic?

Tags: traffic, high-traffic

I'd like to ask "What exactly is considered *a lot of traffic* for a website?"

What's the minimum someone could say - after stating their website receives a lot of traffic - as to not be laughed at?

*Inspired by [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/647210/just-what-is-a-big-database) on stack overflow*

Comment: This is quite subjective, but then that other question was too, but yielded some good answers. Can you edit it so the people who aren't in the UK during the week 7 to 13 August 2011 and saw that particular programme aren't confused by the Dragon's Den reference? Actually I think that person didn't think that was a lot of traffic, I think the person was making the point it wasn't a lot of traffic, but that's not your question.

Comment: @Paul done!  I know this is subjective and your niche is quite important but I agree the other question was interesting and I'd like to know peoples thoughts.

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I've created the following scale to help give some feel of what "a lot" might mean. It uses estimates of **unique monthly visitors** for popular websites to create a high point, then works down from there.

#### The "what's a lot of traffic?" scale (monthly uniques):

```
"A right royal load"  =   1 billion+      e.g. Google
"A mother load"       =   500 million+    e.g. Facebook
"A crap load"         =   100 million+    e.g. Wikipedia
"A boat load"         =   10 million+     e.g. News sites, StackExchange
"A lot"               =   1 million+      e.g. Very popular blogs, Web shops
"Quite a lot"         =   100,000+        e.g. Popular blogs
"Small fish"          =   0 - 100,000     e.g. Your mate Dave's tumblog
```

Examples below based on collected data points of varying accuracy and usefulness:

#### 1 billion unique monthly visitors (a right royal load)

Google's estimated monthly unique visitor count is around a billion, as reported by the Wall Street Journal [here](http://blogs.wsj.com/digits/2011/06/21/google-notches-one-billion-unique-visitors-per-month/) in June 2011, based on comScore's estimates.

#### 714 million unique monthly visitors (a mother load)

Facebook's monthly visitors are almost as high as Google's, according to the same [comScore report](http://www.comscoredatamine.com/2011/06/google-reaches-1-billion-global-visitors/) that the Wall Street Journal cited.

#### 400 million unique monthly visitors (a crap load)

The Wikimedia foundation [reports](http://stats.wikimedia.org/reportcard/) around 400 million monthly uniques for all Wikimedia sites worldwide (e.g. Wikipedia).

#### 46 million unique monthly visitors (a boat load)

A popular news site, such as the Guardian [reports](http://www.guardian.co.uk/advertising/display-audience-guardian-traffic-users) its monthly unique browser count at about 46 million. This is in line with other large news websites: The Huffington Post reported 36.6 million uniques and the The New York Times reported 35.5 million uniques, both from the US alone [[source](http://mashable.com/2011/06/09/huffington-post-surpasses-new-york-times/)].

#### 20 million unique monthly visitors (a boat load)

A popular Q&A family of sites, such as the StackExchange network, sees around 20 million uniques per month, according to [union square ventures](http://www.usv.com/2011/03/stack-overflow-becomes-stack-exchange.php) in March 2011.

#### 8 million unique monthly vistors (a lot)

A popular shopping site such as [ASOS](http://asos.com) has around [8 million monthly uniques](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASOS.com). That's still a lot.

#### 5 million unique monthly visitors (a lot)

A very popular blog, such as Matthew Inman's [TheOatmeal](http://TheOatmeal.com) receives around [5 million](http://theoatmeal.com/) monthly unique visitors.

#### More than 100,000 unique monthly visitors (quite a lot)

Popular and moderately famous blogs and sites live in this band. (Anecdotal data point: I used to run a small popular blog that got about this amount of traffic. It's a healthy amount of traffic to have. It's also about the number of monthly uniques you need to make AdSense/ad units worthwhile, in my opinion.)

#### Fewer than 100,000 unique monthly visitors (small fish)

Everything else—hobbyist blogs and websites—fall here.

#### Notes

"A lot" is a relative term, so it's important to note that the scale above is only a very loose guideline. Many webmasters would be perfectly happy with a few thousand uniques a month for a personal blog, for example, and may well deem that "a lot". It depends entirely on the context, the competition, and the extent to which your own sense of achievement is inflated by lots of zeros.

Still, it's fun to see how far the scale reaches.

Comment: very nice scale, it does put things into perspective. i would be very happy with 100k hits, let alone uniques.... but it's very subjective, for me 100 uniques in a month would be a lot at this point.

Comment: Great post, thanks!  I still think however the small fish scale needs to be broken up, there is an important and distinct difference imo between 1,000 monthly uniques, 50,000 uniques and 99,000 uniques.  Is this a good Community Wiki question?

Comment: @Tom Gullen Most of the world's websites will likely fall in the 'small fish' band. It would be very hard to subcategorise sites within those bands in the same way that I've done above. There might be a distinct difference between sites that have 1k monthly uniques and those that have 99k monthly uniques in terms of design, content, and promotion, for example, but there is probably little quantifiable difference that would allow them to be subcategorised.

Comment: This scale is cool. Great Job :)

Comment: Nice scale but I think your should also factor in the size of the site. If you have a 5,000 page site, then a million unique visitors would be quite different from a 5 page site with a million unique visitors.

Comment: I am a small fish :|

Comment: The real value is as a percentage of your target audience - if your target audience is 100 people and you get 80 unique visits, you're big fish in that demographic.

Comment: 100k uniques is far from "small fish" - it means there are thousands of people searching for and finding your site every day. An ecommerce shop getting 3,500 visits a day is likely making solid sales. I would say anything up to 1,000 visits/day is small fish.

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat 100k is a lot to many. It's hard to know where to draw the line, though. I drew it at 100k, which felt about right to me when the scale goes up to a billion; if a 'popular' site is getting 1m unique hits/month, 100k *is* 'small fish', and your suggestion of 30k uniques/month doesn't seem that different to me. It's so hard to define a universal scale that attempting to do so is simply stating an opinion. Perhaps if I'd called it 'not as much' instead of 'small fish', it might prove less contentious.

Comment: Small fish is a contentious label definitely, but regardless going to smaller quantities even if it is just an educated opinion is still in the spirit of the question imo and useful (and I think everyone would recognise that and take answers with a pinch of salt) .

The problem I have with it is an abandoned old blog pulling in 100 uniques a month is grouped with a medium sized site with 50,000 uniques monthly has more actual disparity than 400 million to 700 million uniques a month.  It is meant to be a semi fun semi serious question though and I appreciate your input :)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat: That's why it's such a subjective question and really depends on factors such as your target market/audience and the context of the comparison. For instance, if you're talking what's big enough to begin load-balancing versus what's big in terms of sites that operate their own data centers versus at what size do you start seeing financial returns from moving from VPS to cloud hosting. Without context, all such labels/classifications are meaningless.

Answer (score 29):

I've just broken down Nicks answer for <100,000 uniques as I think it needs expanding a bit :)

#### 50,000 unique monthly visitors (a pop)

A healthy amount of visitors and showing the signs of value

#### 25,000 unique monthly visitors (a buzz)

Healthy interest

#### 10,000 unique monthly visitors (a fizz)

Signs of potential for small sites

#### 2,500 unique monthly visitors (a beep)

A blog/info site with a reasonable amount of interest

#### 500 unique monthly visitors (a pip)

A very small blog visited only by a handful of people.

#### 100 unique monthly visitors (a blip)

A tiny blip on the Internet.

#### 20 unique monthly visitor (friends and family)

A website probably only visited by yourself and friends and family

Comment: Glad I wasn't the only one finding it a bit thin down there!

Answer (score 4):

The ["How Much Traffic Do You Need To Make $100,000 With Google AdSense"](http://www.minterest.org/how-much-traffic-do-you-need-to-make-money/) could be another scale

Comment: i think your link has gone stale or i am not finding the info I need regarding adsense + traffic correlation. heres another http://www.minterest.org/how-much-traffic-do-you-need-to-make-money/

Answer (score 2):

I think it depends. If you have a niche website with 10,000 monthly visitors, this could be a lot of traffic, too.

Answer (score 0):

If this is about Social Proof, and getting yourself in a Measuring contest one useful tool is the *Benchmarking* feature of Google Analytics.

[image: Google Analytics Benchmarking]

Every website is different, so in case you are curious to see how other people in similar industries, geo graphic location or other metrics this is quite a useful tool to know things like 'Yeah, SEO is a good channel for us. Social, not so much.'

Answer (score -2):

lot's of talkers on here.  haha.   Here's the real scoop.  It depends on your goals.  For businesses, traffic is somewhat irrelevant.  Focus instead on conversions.  For the ego, traffic is nice.  Regarding what other hard working people are able to achieve...it's absurd to compare anyone on here to google or facebook or wikipedia.  Very few websites in the whole world get 1 million hits.  100/month is a good start.  1,000 is a great start.  10,000 is damn good.  100,000 is holy poop super duper amazing. 250,000 is 'Fa-get about it!'

Comment: "250,000 is 'Fa-get about it!'" What does "very few" mean? I've worked for a relatively-small niche site ranked 50k+ at Alexa which clears [250k+ visits/mo](http://i.imgur.com/kEWd7Dg.png) on a regular basis - this would seem to indicate that there are actually quite a few sites clearing > 250k visits/mo.